# Pesquisa dentro de duas arrays

Tags: javascript, array, indexof

o caso eh o seguinte. tenho um script que queria usar e como em todas as perguntas "suponho" não sei como fazer. eh o seguinte quero fazer uma pesquisa de dados do array com javascript "pq não sugiram outras linguagens se sua resposta não for em javascript por favor não responda" dentro de outro array assim:

eu tenho a array comprimento:

```
var comprimentos = new Array('OI', 'OLA', 'IAI', 'BLZ', 'TESTE', 'TUDO BEM', 'JOIA');
```

mas pra cobrir todas as opçoes como por exemplo 'oi?' que eh diferente de 'oi' devido a interrogação criei uma segunda array

```
var int = new Array('?', '!', '');
```

entao pensei em algo assim:

```
var comprimentos = new Array('OI'+int[y], 'OLA'+int[y], 'IAI'+int[y], 'BLZ'+int[y], 'TESTE'+int[y], 'TUDO BEM'+int[y], 'JOIA'+int[y]);
```

sendo que a var y equivale a um numero randomico que varia entre 0 e 2

mas tenho que confirmar varias vezes o código ta dando muito erro me ajudem ai

Comment: Ficou meio confuso. Você quer verificar se em um determinado texto contem algum dos termos da var comprimento, mas pode haver as variações do segundo array, o que interfere na busca dos itens do primeiro array é isso?

Comment: BASICAMENTE ELE FAZIA O SEGUINTE:

Comment: QUANDO EU PESQUISAVA OI ELE DAVA A RESPOSTA PROGRAMADA POREM SE COLOCASE OI! JA NAO DAVA. E O USUARIO FINAL VC SABE COMO EH: IMPREVISIVEL! ELES ESCREVEM COISAS COMO IAI E VC FICA PENSANDO QUE ELE VAI ESCREVER OI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para obter todas as ocorrências da concatenação dos 2 arrays, basta uni-los dessa forma...

```js
var comprimentos = new Array('OI', 'OLA', 'IAI', 'BLZ', 'TESTE', 'TUDO BEM', 'JOIA');

var int = new Array('?', '!', ' ');

var ocorrencias = [];

comprimentos.forEach(function(c){
  ocorrencias.push(c);
  int.forEach(function(i){
    ocorrencias.push(c+i);
  });
});

console.log(ocorrencias);
```

Comment: FUNCIONOU COMO UMA LUVA AMIGO OBRIGADO VOU ESTUDAR MAIS OS CONCEITOS DO SEU CODIGO PORQUE USEI MAS NAO FAÇO IDEIA DE COMO FUNCIONA AINDA MAS DE TODO MODO MUITO OBRIGADO

Comment: SE DESSE PRA DAR LIKE NA RESPOSTA ACREDITE EU DAVA

Comment: kkk, aí sim, javascript é uma mão na roda, a próposito like tem como dar o.o, aqui você pode até escolher a resposta que te ajudou como melhor, no canto superior esquerdo, abaixo dos votos